# How to calculate distance using accelerometer using iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-location, accelerometer

What is the best way to calculate the distance between two points/Or we can say while we walk calculate distance traveled using accelerometer? My main question is that i'm working on an application in which i need to count distance using two locations but sometimes the core locations fails to update location so at that time how do i calculate the distance traveled?

Comment: Someone forgot to pay attention in Physics class!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can't even get an accurate measurement of velocity from the accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994018/measuring-velocity-via-iphone-sdk), so you're *definitely* not going to be able to get an accurate measure of distance traveled.