# CMDeviceMotion userAcceleration is upside down?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm seeing some unexpected readings from the userAcceleration field in CMDeviceMotion. When I look at the raw accelerometer data from CMAccelerometerData, I see that if the iPhone is flat on a table the reading is 1G straight down (1G in -Z axis) and if I drop the iphone (on a soft surface of course) then the acceleromtere reading goes to zero as expected. That's all fine. When I instead use the CMDeviceMotion class, the userAcceleration reading is zero as expected when the iPhone is flat on table. Again this is fine. But when I drop the iPhone and read the CMDeviceManager userAcceleration, the userAcceleration values are 1G straight up (+Z) not down (-Z) as expected. It appears that the userAcceleration readings are actually the exact opposite of what acceleration the device is really experiencing. Has anyone else observed this? Can I just invert (multiply by -1) all the userAcceleration values before I try to integrate for velocity and position, or am I misunerstanding what userAcceleration is reading?

Answer (score 6):

There are some conceptual differences between [CMAccelerometerData.acceleration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAccelerometerData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMAccelerometerData/acceleration) and [CMDeviceMotion.userAcceleration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMDeviceMotion/userAcceleration)

1. Raw accelerometer data is just the sum of all accelerations measured i.e. a combination of gravity and current acceleration of the device.
2. Device motion data is the result of sensor fusion of all 3 sensors i.e. accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. Thus bias and errors are eliminated (in theory) and the remaining acceleration data is separated into gravity and acceleration to be used conveniently.

So if you want to compare both you have to check `CMAccelerometerData.acceleration` against `CMDeviceMotion.userAcceleration + CMDeviceMotion.gravity` to compare like with like.

In general CMDeviceMotion is your first choice in most cases when you want precise values and hardware independency.

Another thing to consider is the [CMAttitudeReferenceFrame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009943-CH1-SW19) you provide when starting Device Motion updates via [startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:). I am not sure what is the default when using the basic version [startDeviceMotionUpdates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startDeviceMotionUpdates)

---

You stated that you want to integrate the values to get velocity and position. There are several discussions about this and at the bottom line I can say it's impossible to get reasonable results. See:

- [Finding distance using accelerometer in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930007/finding-distance-using-accelerometer-in-iphone)
- [Getting displacement from accelerometer data with Core Motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449565/getting-displacement-from-accelerometer-data-with-core-motion)
- [How can I find distance traveled with a gyroscope and accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647314/need-to-find-distance-using-gyroaccelerometer/6648538#6648538)

If your app concept forces you to rely on precise results for more than half a second, try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the CMAcceleration is not obey the right hand rule, which x is point to left, y is point to the screen bottom, in that case, with a typical right hand system, z axis should point to the upper side,but its not.
It makes me uncomfortable when dealing with motion sensors!