# detecting a mobile device flat movement in 2D space - is it possible?

Tags: mobile, air, camera, accelerometer, gyroscope

I program mobile apps using Adobe AIR but i guess this question refers to mobile development in general.

I would like to do something like a 2d drawing app with the movement of the mobile device itself in space. For instance, holding the phone flat horizontally on my palm and "drawing" a square in space would draw a square on the screen. This would require the user to calibrate a start point and also decide if the plane is horizontal or vertical.

Could this be done with the accelerometer, gyroscope, or a combination of the two?
If not (since steady movement with no acceleration isn't detected - right?) can this be achieved with the camera always open and detecting general movement in a 2d plane?

thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting displacement from accelerometer data with Core Motion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449565/getting-displacement-from-accelerometer-data-with-core-motion)

Comment: See also the links provided in [CMDeviceMotion userAcceleration is upside down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527593/cmdevicemotion-useracceleration-is-upside-down/16530662#16530662). Although the most it is related to iPhone programming, it refers to mobile development is general. Without an external reference system it is impossible to get acceptable accuracy.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope the shock is not too hard :-) I spent some time on it and it turned out to be wasted